# How to read RSS feed as a datasource?

Tags: java

How to read RSS feed as a datasource?

e.g. I am using Java code. How do I read the RSS feed URL as a datasource and populate a table listing in my page?

Any advise or sample code to provide. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is simpler to build a external process that reads the selected RSS sources and stores them into a table. Then your Java program can access with a Connection from DataSource with the proper JDBC driver.

Answer (score 0):

RSS feed are XML File, So In order to read them You should know how to parse XML in JAVA.  [This](http://www.vogella.com/articles/RSSFeed/article.html) will be helpful to understand the whole concept.